# Multi-Select listbox - check if user selected Select All option

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a MultiSelect Listbox

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.DealerScopeDealerProvider.DealerScopeProvider, new MultiSelectList(providers, "ProviderCode", "ProviderName"), new { id = "providerfilter" })


$('#providerfilter').multiselect({
    search: true,
    selectAll: true,
});
```

which renders **HTML** like this:

```
<select id="providerfilter" multiple="multiple">
<option></option>
</select>
<div>
<a href="#" class="ms-selectall global chkimg">Select all</a>
<a href="#" class="ms-unselectall global unchkimg">Unselect all</a>
<a href="#" class="crosimg"></a>
</div>
```

I want to know if user selected *Select all* option or not. How can I achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

use below jquery to get weather checkbox is select or not

```
  if ($('.ms-selectall').is(":checked")) 
  {   
     // selectall button is selected 
  }
  else if($('.ms-unselectall ').is(":checked")) 
  {
     // unselectall  button is selected  
  }
```

Comment: no it doesnt equal to true even when I chose select all

Comment: please check your javascript is loaded proper or not, and if loaded then apply specific id to checkbox and then use it

Comment: JavaScript is loaded and ids are proper too

Comment: use checkbox instead of anchor tag, and if you want to continue with anchor, then handle your task with click event of js